# onActivityResult never fires unless I use getActivity() when calling startActivityForResult from a Fragment

Tags: android-dialogfragment, onactivityresult, start-activity

My main activity opens a dialog fragment with 2 items in a listview. Clicking either one starts a new Activity. Unless I use getActivity().startActivityForResult() my code for onActivityResult never runs. Everything I've read here discourages using getActivity().startActivityForResult() and says just use startActivityForResult(). Normally I'd say "doesn't matter, code works" but its driving me nuts why its discouraged so much and why it won't work without getActivity(). I've been pouring over documentation and can't find an answer, help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

My onActivityResult() code located in my main activity (Landing.class):

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String s = "";
    Session current = new Session();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            s = data.getStringExtra("SESSION_JSON");
            current = gson.fromJson(s, Session.class);
        }
    }
    sessions.add(current);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Code that calls startActivityForResult() located in my DialogFragment class:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    dismiss();
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActiveSessionActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Code in ActiveSessionActivity class that should be returning the result to onActivityResult() in my main activity:

```
    public void saveSession(View v) {
    Session session;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(session);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("SESSION_JSON", json);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android DialogFragments are still fragments, as such calling startActivityForResult from your dialog will actually be getting the result in the dialog. If you were to implement onActivityResult in your DialogFragment you'll get your callback. The reason getActivity().startActivityForResult() is discouraged is because the dialog has no control of the activity and it might not be attached anymore. Try...

```
if (getActivity() != null && !isDetached() && !isRemoving()) {
  getActivity().startActivityForResult(...);
}
```